# How to get and set data related to monthly data plans?

Tags: android, bandwidth

I want to see and modify the monthly data plan limit (if set) in an Android device.
Can anybody pinpoint which direction to go?
Edit: I am also a programmer, probably that's why I didn't explain myself better.
I want to access the information about the plan that a user configures in their own mobile, asDavid pointed out here:
http://www.simplemobilereview.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/android-data-usage.png

Obviously I don't care about what the user really has contrated with his carrier... this is about programming.

Comment: You are at wrong place...This is a site programmers.

Comment: I think everyone is reading the question in the wrong way. He's asking if there's an API to read/write the limit that you can read/write in the "Data Usage" page, which is a system app. I don't think there is an API to access it, but asking it shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: http://www.simplemobilereview.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/android-data-usage.png This page.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the Android SDK for accessing information about data plans.

You are welcome to iterate over the world's mobile carriers and ask each if they have some Web service API that you can use to access this information. Few will have such an API.